# Creating an Azure app registration using Bicep : which privileges are needed?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-bicep

I'd like to create an app registration in a deployment script using Bicep.
A user-assigned managed identity is used to run the deployment script.
But the identity doesn't have the sufficient privileges to create the app registration.
What role assignment should the identity have?

```json
resource appRegistration 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  tags: tags
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: { '${identity.id}': {} }
  }
  properties: {
    azCliVersion: '2.9.1'
    retentionInterval: 'P1D'
    arguments: name
    scriptContent: '''
      APPREGNAME=$1
      az login --identity
      clientid=$(az ad app create --display-name $APPREGNAME --query appId --output tsv)
      $DeploymentScriptOutputs['clientId'] = clientId
      '''
  }
}
```

Error:

```
DeploymentScriptError: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

[This](https://reginbald.medium.com/creating-app-registration-with-arm-bicep-b1d48a287abb) article is speaking about an Application Administrator role, but I can't find that role when I'm trying to add a role assignment to the identity in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Application Admin Role is a MS Entra ID (Azure AD) role.

Comment: You can otherwise give Graph Permissiom :`Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` (app permission) but same it is MS Entra ID permission.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** that: I agree with @*Thomas*, to create Azure AD Application, the managed identity must have **Application Administrator Role** or  `Application.ReadWrite.All` or `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` application permissions based on your requirement.

To resolve the error "***Insufficient privileges to complete the operation***" check the below:

Assign **Application Administrator Role** to the managed identity:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID roles and administrators -> Select Application Administrator -> Add assignment -> Select members -> Search your managed identity -> Assign*

[image]

**Otherwise**, try assigning `Application.ReadWrite.All` or `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`  API permissions to managed identity like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount

$DestinationTenantId = "TenantID"
$MsiName = "ruk" 
$oPermissions = @(
  "Application.ReadWrite.All"
  "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy"
  
)

$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" #Dont change this

$oMsi = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$MsiName'"
$oGraphSpn = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$GraphAppId'"

$oAppRole = $oGraphSpn.AppRole | Where-Object {($_.Value -in $oPermissions) -and ($_.AllowedMemberType -contains "Application")}

Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $DestinationTenantId

foreach($AppRole in $oAppRole)
{
  $oAppRoleAssignment = @{
    "PrincipalId" = $oMSI.Id
    "ResourceId" = $oGraphSpn.Id
    "AppRoleId" = $AppRole.Id
  }
  
  New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment `
    -ServicePrincipalId $oAppRoleAssignment.PrincipalId `
    -BodyParameter $oAppRoleAssignment `
    -Verbose
}
```

[image]

The API permissions are granted successfully to the managed identity:

[image]

***Now run the Bicep deployment script after assigning the role or the API permissions and now the Azure AD application will be created successfully.***